# stringdist_join results in NAs

Tags: r, matching, fuzzy, stringdist, fuzzyjoin

i am experimenting with the stringdist package in order to make fuzzy joins and i run into a problem which i do not understand and fail to find an answer for.
I want to join these 2 data tables with the "dl" method and it produces a NA, which i completely do not understand. Maybe one of you has an explanation for this.
The code:

```
library(fuzzyjoin)
test1<-as.data.frame(test1<-c("techniker"))
test2<-as.data.frame(test2<-c("technician"))
setnames(test2,1,"label")
setnames(test1,1,"label")
x <- stringdist_join(test1, test2, by = "label", mode = "left", distance_col="distance", method="dl")
```

if i use the jaccard method however, there is a match:

```
y <- stringdist_join(test1, test2, by = "label", mode = "left", distance_col="distance", method="jaccard", q=4)
```

Hope anyone can clarify.

Cheers
Dome

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`max_dist` is set to 2 by default.

The `dl` distance between `"tekniker"` and `"technician"` is more than 2.

so there's no match.

```
stringdist_join(test1, test2, by = "label", mode = "left", distance_col="distance", method="dl",max_dist=5)
#     label.x label.y distance
# 1 techniker  techni        3
```